# bash script to upload files to sftp

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sftp

I'm looking to create a smart script to upload files to an sftp site. I cannot use scp because i have no control of the sftp site plus the vendor doesn't allow public key authentication.

```
#!/bin/bash

            read -p "Do you want to list the sftp site contents (y/n): " list
            read -p "Upload Selected file, type the name of the file: " uploadfilename


    conenctsfttp() {
            export SSHPASS=****
            sshpass -e sftp -oBatchMode=no -b - testuser@example.com
    }

    listfiles() {
            if [[ $list = y ]];
            then
            conenctsfttp <<< $'ls\n bye'
            else
            echo not list
            fi
    }

    uploadfilen() {
    #        if [[ $uploadfilename = y ]];
    #        then
            conenctsfttp << EOF
            put $(uploadfilename)
    EOF
    }

    listfiles
    uploadfilen
```

how can i make the script read the filename and upload the file to the sftp server. The file-name is never picked up and it goes into an infinite loop. If possible i like to define a location of where files are located for the upload.

Comment: so what's the problem with this? read the filename from WHERE?

Comment: when i do upload by file name i add the file name but it goes in a infinite loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(uploadfilename)` should be `$uploadfilename`.

`$(...)` is an alternative form of command substitution. To reference (retrieve) a value from a variable, you want to use the `$variable` syntax.

Comment: some how calling the function uploadfilen() does not  invoke the file name that its grabbed from the user input.... it also needs to invoke the connection to upload the file...